# Change bgcolor when click button

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android to create a Quiz application. So far, most of the things are done. Only one problem. When the answer button is clicked, its background color should be changed to a different color.

I implement in this way:

```
selectionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                correct answer clicked
                if (checkChosen(questionProgress, selectionBtn.getText().toString())) {
//                    change the bg-color to green indicates user made correct choice
                    selectionBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_button_selected);
//                    last the bg-color for 0.3s
                    selectionBtn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            selectionBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.choice_button_border);
                        }
                    }, 300);
                } else {
//                    wrong answer clicked
                    selectionBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_button_selected);
                    selectionBtn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            selectionBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.choice_button_border);
                        }
                    }, 300);
                }
//                progress added
                questionProgress++;
                /**
                 * progress equals the amount, means the last question
                 * show the submit button
                 */
                if (questionProgress == questionAmount) {
                    binding.submitBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    binding.progressBar.setProgress(binding.progressBar.getMax());
                    binding.progressCount.setText(questionAmount + " / " + questionAmount);
                }
                /**
                 * progress < amount, remove answer buttons of the last question
                 * add new answer buttons and change progress bar
                 */
                if (questionProgress < questionList.length) {
                    Log.v("progress", String.valueOf(questionProgress));
                    binding.progressBar.setProgress(questionProgress);
                    binding.progressCount.setText(questionProgress + " / " + questionAmount);
                    binding.quizContent.setText(questionList[questionProgress]);
                    binding.selectionLayout.removeAllViews();
                    String[] anLi = answerMap.get(questionProgress);
                    for (int i = 0; i < anLi.length - 1; i++) {
                        addSelections(anLi[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

However, in this way, only answer buttons for the last question will change bg-color when they are clicked.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to reuse `selectionBtn` variable while creating new button for each answer, when your delayed runnable starts, the value of `selectionBtn` will be different and it will be pointing the last button you created.

To fix that, use the `onClick()`'s argument, which actually is the view that triggered the event (which is your correct button):

```java
selectionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Button currentButton = (Button) view;
        
        if (checkChosen(questionProgress, currentButton.getText().toString())) {
            currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_button_selected);
        } else {
            currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_button_selected);
        }

        currentButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.choice_button_border);
            }
        }, 300);

        ....
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and Yohannes, but it's still not working. I think it's the problem that I used the `binding.selectionLayout.removeAllViews();` before re-creating new answer buttons. I think this removed the full view and all the buttons so that I can't see the buttons flash. But I don't know how to fix this... Can you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **view** from onClick method like in the code snippet below.

```
selectionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        if (checkChosen(questionProgress, selectionBtn.getText().toString())) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct_button_selected);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.choice_button_border);
                }
            }, 200);
        } else {
            // else condition
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. The problem is `removeAllViews()`. It removes the whole views for answer buttons before add new buttons, and that makes the flash not visible cause it's removed.

```
if (questionProgress < questionList.length) {
                    Log.v("progress", String.valueOf(questionProgress));
                    binding.progressBar.setProgress(questionProgress);
                    binding.progressCount.setText(questionProgress + " / " + questionAmount);
                    binding.quizContent.setText(questionList[questionProgress]);
                    binding.selectionLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            binding.selectionLayout.removeAllViews();
                            String[] anLi = answerMap.get(questionProgress);
                            for (int i = 0; i < anLi.length - 1; i++) {
                                addSelections(anLi[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 300);

                }
```

This is how I fixed it.